# Unable to remove white space from right in responsive design HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am unable to remove the white space from right side when implementing responsive design. 
I have used **flex box** to implement most of the layout.
The window responds accurately and content adjusts accordingly but when scrolled, there is space on the right always!

Hierarchy of classes:

----> container

--------> sidebar

----------------> name-profession

----------------> details

------------------------> contact-item

--------> content

[image: screenshot-extra space on right]

HTML:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E6EA;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}


/* Sidebar */

.sidebar {
  background-color: #FFF;
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  flex: initial;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.name-profession {
  background-color: #56b293;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #fff;
}

.name {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.profession {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.details {
  padding: 40px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .details {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .contact-item {}
}

.contact {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}


/* End Sidebar */


/* Content */

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  flex: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}


/* End Content */


/* Common */

.large-heading {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.content-text {
  color: grey;
}

.circle-avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #56b293;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle-avatar img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dotted-separator {
  border-top: 3px dashed #E5E6EA;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-padding {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <!--Sidebar-->
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="name-profession">
      <p class="name">Gurleen Sethi</p>
      <p class="profession">Software Developer</p>
    </div>

    <div class="details">
      <p class="contact large-heading">Contact</p>
      <div class="contact-item">
        <div class="circle-avatar">
          <img src="images/home.png">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-text">
          <p class="heading">Address</p>
          <p class="content-text">948 New Geeta Colony</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-item">
        <div class="circle-avatar">
          <img src="images/calendar.png">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-text">
          <p class="heading">DATE OF BIRTH</p>
          <p class="content-text">18 August 1996</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-item">
        <div class="circle-avatar">
          <img src="images/phone.png">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-text">
          <p class="heading">Phone</p>
          <p class="content-text">+91 72908 32506</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-item">
        <div class="circle-avatar">
          <img src="images/mail.png">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-text">
          <p class="heading">Email</p>
          <p class="content-text">contactgurleensethi@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-item">
        <div class="circle-avatar">
          <img src="images/world.png">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-text">
          <p class="heading">Website</p>
          <p class="content-text">www.thetechnocafe.com</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Content-->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="about content-padding">
      <p class="heading" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">About</p>
      <p class="content-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="dotted-separator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.contact-item` has width of `400px` which on mobile creates the horizontal space. Change it to `width: 100%` and it should be okay.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue; the page has white space in the right section. I used "inspect" but did not see any section overflowed. So I tried the below code from other solutions, it worked for me. Maybe it can help you.

```
html,body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Finally working perfectly after added this to App.js in React. Thank you a million times!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code only media query i think this issue  resolved

**Replace this code**

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .details {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .sidebar {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple CSS to prevent this problem if you do not require horizontal scrolling on your website.

```
html{
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

if you want it to only affect mobile devices, I suggest you put it in the appropriate @media block like below

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    html{
      width: 100vw;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

If you get any div not appearing properly, you can make the width of that div 100% like below

```
.div-class-name{
    width:100%;
}
```